# How to parse this json using python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I know its kind of trivial thing to ask...but i'm a new bee to python.
Here is a json string

```
reply = {u'f': [{u'v': u'0'}]}
```

How to parse out value 0 from it using python.
i tried like

```
count = reply['rows'][0]['v']
```

but it not working

Comment: Where did the `rows` come from? (also that's not a JSON string).

Comment: As a side note, that's not a json string.  That's a dictionary...

Comment: Welcome to the Hive, new bee!

Comment: @mgilson Except it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @mgilson, the Python unicode marker (`u""`) would stand in the way as it is. Of course, you can always use the `json` module to turn it into a JSON string.

Comment: @NullUserException -- pretend to know something that you don't, end up looking stupid.  :-).  that's what I just learned!  I've edited my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count = reply['f'][0]['v']` should work I believe.

`reply` is a dictionary.  As such, you need to use the dictionary keys to access the data.  In this case, the key is `'f'`, not `'rows'`.

Comment: +1 If you look at `reply`, you'll see it has an `f` and no `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had valid JSON, you could use the simplejson module:

```
from simplejson import loads, dumps

my_dict = loads(my_json_serialized_string)
```

and then you can access the python dict, e.g.,:

```
print my_dict.items()
print my_dict.keys()
print my_dict.values()

#lets assume 'rows' exists as a key, and the value is a list, and the first item of that list is a dict that contains the key 'v':
print my_dict['rows'][0]['v']
```

and you can even change the dict, and serialize it as a valid JSON string:

```
my_dict['my_key'] = 'my_value'

my_other_json_serialized_string = dumps(my_dict)
```